# How long does it take to transfer btc with 5 sats

Tags: btce

I transferred 10 dollars to a gambling website and its been over a day and it still hasent reached its first confirmation, when will it actually hit it?
https://explorer.bitcoin.com/btc/tx/6d114e6f8d96f53a1aa8b9e8e6d66eeb4aedc4efa57d537a25f54bb7157f0ccb

Comment: This might take a month considering 5 sat/vb.

Comment: If the above doesn't answer your question. Use segwit, rbf, fee rate based on urgency of tx and fee rate used by [others](https://mempool.observer), Layer 2 for quick transfer and low fee: LN, Liquid etc.